# In the tutorial part II, why can Alloy compose root with parent?

Tags: alloy

In the [File System Lesson II of the Alloy Tutorial](https://alloytools.org/tutorials/online/frame-FS-3.html), the following model is described:

```
// A file system object in the file system
abstract sig FSObject { }

// File system objects must be either directories or files.
sig File, Dir extends FSObject { }

// A File System
sig FileSystem {
  root: Dir,
  live: set FSObject,
  contents: Dir lone-> FSObject,
  parent: FSObject ->lone Dir
}{
  // root has no parent
  no root.parent
  // live objects are reachable from the root
  live in root.*contents
  // parent is the inverse of contents
  parent = ~contents
}
```

Note the `no root.parent` fact.

The question is: why can Alloy compose root with parent, given that root is a `Dir`, and `Dir`s do not have parent relations? (only `FileSystem`s have parent relations)

Answer (score 0):

By defining `parent` as a field of `FileSystem`, it gets the type

```
FileSystem -> FSObject -> Dir
```

Within the signature fact, there is an implicit `this`, so `root.parent` is short for `(this.root).(this.parent)`, which means we're joining the types `Dir` and `FSObject -> Dir`. Since `FSObject` includes `Dir`, this join is not redundant, and yields a set of type `Dir`.